# ML.NET load a new model into prediction engine pool after startup

Tags: ml.net

I have 2 .NET Core Web API projects setup as Docker containers, one for training and another for predictions. In the prediction service, I create the PredictionEnginePool the scalable way based on this - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/machine-learning/how-to-guides/serve-model-web-api-ml-net

When the user submits a request to the training API to train a new model, the model.zip file is saved to a PersistentVolume which is accessible by the prediction service as well. After that, the user will submit another request for prediction. How do I load this newly trained model into the prediction engine pool without restarting the prediction API ?

Also, how can I check whether a model exists in the pool by modelName?

Can you provide sample codes that dynamically read .zip files from a folder, check if they're already in the pool and if not then add it into the prediction pool, all done outside of the startup.cs maybe inside a controller or a service layer?

Answer (score 1):

What about using FromUri? This will poll the location of the model, e.g. a blob storage for any changes. I'm not sure if a change forces the application to restart but I don't think so.

```html
    builder.Services.AddPredictionEnginePool<SentimentData, SentimentPrediction>()
  .FromUri(
      modelName: "SentimentAnalysisModel",
      uri:"https://github.com/dotnet/samples/raw/master/machine-learning/models/sentimentanalysis/sentiment_model.zip",
      period: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1));
```

Comment: I do have to load from file but can you share the codes on how you setup the builder.Services? Are you calling this outside of the startup.cs?

Comment: It's the same setup as you would if you load it from a file actually (so within Startup.cs). INstead of calling .FromFile you call .FromUri.

Comment: I’m calling the FromFile now but it doesn’t work outside the startup.cs using the prediction engine pool

Comment: I think you can call an override for FromFile which will watch for changes: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.ml.builderextensions.fromfile?view=ml-dotnet

Comment: Thanks but how can u access the engine pool outside of Startup.cs? The new model trained has a different filename than those already in the pool so the watch for changes wont track it. How do you add this new file into the engine pool dynamically past startup without restarting it?

Comment: Thank you for clarifying, that's very helpful. Follow up question, what's the reason that the new model has a different name? I would assume the application is already wired up to use a specific set of input/output defined. Is it so that we can keep track of versions? I can't think of a good way to dynamically inject it. It seems like a function that's missing here is "LoadFromDirectory" which watches for changes in a blob container and you can load anything from the blob container dynamically maybe?

Comment: It has a different name because it is a brand new model. The users can upload a new training data to create a new model anytime and should be able to predict immediately after the training is completed. I hope ML.NET community can come up with a new feature that goes like PredictionEnginePool.AddModel(modelName: XXX, modelPath: YYY); and make it accessible outside of the startup.cs

Comment: Very interesting concept. Please add an issue for it on the ML.NET repo and that may be something I'll work on

Comment: Would this solve my issue? https://github.com/dotnet/machinelearning/pull/4393

Comment: I did create an issue as well - https://github.com/dotnet/machinelearning/issues/5096. I might join as a contributer as i badly need this feature!

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

I partially had the same problem. I need to load my model from Azure Blob Storage, through the client. The `fromUri()` method was not sufficient. After seeing the pull request from the comments, I have managed to make the following work:

First, I created a custom model loader implementation:

```
public class AzureModelLoader : ModelLoader
{
private IServiceProvider _provider;
public AzureModelLoader(IServiceProvider provider)
{
    _provider = provider;
    
}

public override IChangeToken GetReloadToken()
{
    //do azure stuff here
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}

public override ITransformer GetModel()
{
    //do azure stuff here
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
}
```

The `PredictionEnginePoolOptions` class contains a ModelLoader property that you can set.
If you don't need to access services, the following code will do:

```
public static void AddPredictionModelsExample(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration,
    bool isDevelopment)
{
    services.AddOptions<PredictionEnginePoolOptions<InputModel, OutputModel>>().Configure(cfg =>
    {
        cfg.ModelLoader = new AzureModelLoader();
    });
    services.AddPredictionEnginePool<InputModel, OutputModel>();

}
```

In case you need access to your serviceprovider to access your other services, the setup is a bit complicated, mostly from the necessary constructor parameters.

```
 public static void AddPredictionModelsExample(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration,
    bool isDevelopment)
{
    services.AddPredictionEnginePool<InputModel, OutputModel>(provider =>
    {
        
        IEnumerable<IConfigureOptions<PredictionEnginePoolOptions<InputModel, OutputModel>>>
            configureOptionsList =
                new List<IConfigureOptions<PredictionEnginePoolOptions<InputModel, OutputModel>>>()
                {
                    new ConfigureOptions<PredictionEnginePoolOptions<InputModel, OutputModel>>(cfg =>
                        cfg.ModelLoader = new AzureModelLoader(provider))
                };
        
        IEnumerable<IPostConfigureOptions<PredictionEnginePoolOptions<InputModel, OutputModel>>>
            postConfigures =
                new List<IPostConfigureOptions<PredictionEnginePoolOptions<InputModel, OutputModel>>>();
        
        var optionsfactory =
            new OptionsFactory<PredictionEnginePoolOptions<InputModel, OutputModel>>(
                configureOptionsList, postConfigures);

        return new PredictionEnginePool<InputModel, OutputModel>(provider,
            provider.GetRequiredService<IOptions<MLOptions>>(), optionsfactory);
    });
}
```

The code aboves does the following:

1. Create a configureoptions list for setup methods.
2. Create a postconfigures list
3. Create an optionsfactiory with the parameters above.
4. Create a `PredictionEnginePool` with the serviceprovider, `IOptions<MLOptions>` (added by the `AddPredictionEnginePool` method) and the optionsfactory.

I have not found any mention of this possibility in the official documentation.  The important detail is that this is necessary to be able to access the serviceprovider when setting the `ModelLoader`.